# Can you achieve fn(x1 ^ fn(x0)) with a fold expression?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Is it possible to achieve the following using a fold expression?

```cpp
template<class... Args>
auto foo(Args... args)
{
    //calling foo(x0, x1, x2) should be exactly equivalent to
    //calling fn(x2 ^ fn(x1 ^ fn(x0)))
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that it has to be a fold expression? This seems like a situation where a simple recursive call with an overload on the number of function arguments would be a much more straight-forward approach.

Comment: @user17732522 Are you saying the answer is no?

Comment: Much simpler would be to put the arguments in an `initializer_list` and iterate or `std::accumulate` over it, assuming the args are all the same type.

Comment: @RaymondChen Initializer list would only work if all arguments are of the same type, wouldn't it? As declared, `foo` may accept arguments of different types.

Comment: Right, I was assuming they were all the same type. Presumably integral, given the `^` operator. Even if different type with overloaded `^`, you can do `int v = 0; auto acc = [&](auto&& x) { v = fn(x^v);}; (acc(args), ...); return v;` - this assumes that `x ^ 0 = x`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Conceivably, `^` could be overloaded and `fn` could be overloaded, and none of the types involved could be convertible to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on a fold expression, something along these lines could probably be made to work (not tested):

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
  T& val;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator^(Wrapper<T> l, Wrapper<U> r) {
  return Wrapper(r.val ^ fn(l.val));
}

template<class... Args>
auto foo(Args... args)
{
  return fn((... ^ Wrapper<Args>(args)).val);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/c7Khzznfa

Comment: @MyClass Well, I didn't promise it worked, only that it could [be made to work](https://godbolt.org/z/8f9qo4oqW) (note that your original `static_assert` has the arguments in the wrong order; the OP wanted the leftmost argument to be the deepest-nested).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you gave me what I asked for. Ted's answer is probably the better solution if you are willing to accept that the order of the arguments are reversed.

Comment: @Chris_F That solution doesn't use a fold expression though, as you for some reason insisted on. The order of arguments issue is [easy enough to fix](https://godbolt.org/z/EM4rKeeee) in that approach, but the lack of fold expression isn't.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a mandatory argument to `foo` and check if you've got additional arguments with a *constexpr-if* inside.

Edit: I accidentally missed the requirement that it should be a fold expression so this uses pack expansion and recursion.

```cpp
template <class T, class... Args>
constexpr auto foo(T&& x, Args&&... args) {    
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args)) {
        return fn(x ^ foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    } else {
        return fn(x);
    }
}
```

This requires that you reverse the arguments when calling the function though:

- `foo(x2, x1, x0)` => `fn(x2 ^ fn(x1 ^ fn(x0)))`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/arqfnWe6M)

Comment: This doesn't use a fold expression though, as was the original requirement. It's just a recursion, as @user17732522 suggested in the very first comment. If the requirement of using fold expression is dropped, your approach could be [tweaked slightly](https://godbolt.org/z/EM4rKeeee) to preserve the original order of arguments.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, yes, you are correct. I was too focused on making it work so I silently dropped the folding part. My bad. Added a note to the answer about it.